# Prove that this complex-valued function can be differentiated

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

$$f(x+iy)\,=\, \sin x\frac{e^y + e^{-y}}2 \,+\,i\cos x\frac{e^y - e^{-y}}2, \quad\quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$
However I have no idea what to do.

Do I need to change this to $z = x + iy$ form first?

Comment: Do you know Cauchy-Riemann's equations?

Comment: I did not know, but I searched it and it helped me a lot! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write
\begin{align*}
f(x + i y) 
&= \sin (x) \cos (iy) + i \cos (x) (-i \sin(i y))\\
&= \sin (x) \cos (iy) + \cos (x) \sin(i y)\\
&= \sin (x + iy),
\end{align*}
with the last line following from the famous trigonometric identity. So actually $f = \sin$, which is complex differentiable everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x+iy)\,=\, u(x,y) +iv(x,y).$$

$$ u(x,y)\,=\,\sin x\cosh y\,=\,\sin x\frac{e^y + e^{-y}}2; $$

$$v(x,y)\,=\,\cos x\sinh y\,=\,\cos x\frac{e^y - e^{-y}}2.$$

$$ u_x(x,y)\,=\,(\sin x)_x\cosh y\,=\,\cos x(\sinh y)_y\,=\,v_y(x,y).$$

$$-v_x(x,y)\,=\,-(\cos x)_x\sinh y\,=\,\sin x(\cosh y)_y\,=\,u_y(x,y).$$

The above is a check that the Cauchy-Riemann PDEs hold, for $f$, at each point of the plane.

Since the first-order partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exist everywhere, and each one is continuous at each point of the plane, we conclude that $f$ is entire.